# Best way of making common views that require database

Tags: php, laravel-4

For example we have menu which will create url by taking slugs and title from the database. All of the pages require menu. While passing the menu datas from controller taken from the database, I will have each controller repeating the same codes, which is not DRY. SO how can I include them in the 'layout' view without requiring each controller to pass the menu datas? If its a simplest one, please forgive, I started laravel today.

Comment: Then welcome to Laravel. This will get you started in the right direction: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers

Comment: Use BaseController constructor or function, get all of your need from parent Class. When you extend your 'new controller' you'll be able to reach all values. Also you can define overriding methods , this will be more useful.

Comment: Thanks! I used view composers. Extending in parent class is also a nice method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Traits. Define a trait class with the methods you need and "use them only in the classes you need. Anything you define in BaseController will be available to everything that extends it which is not what you need

### MenuTrait

```
trait MenuControls 
{
    public function createMenu()
    {

    }
}
```

### Your Class that needs menu controls:

```
class INeedMenusController extends BaseController
{
    use MenuControls;

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $someVar = $this->createMenu();
    }
}
```